# Struts2 and form validation of prefilled forms

Tags: struts2

I'm using the `validate()` - method of struts2 to validate the form input. In my `struts.xml` I can define a result with name "input" which is displayed if the validation fails. This for the context :-)

Now my question: the form I want to validate contains a selectbox which is filled out of a database. The first time the form is displayed everything works fine. But if I validate the form and the "input" - result is displayed, I get an `IOException` because of the iterator which outputs the db-result into my selectbox. Is there a solution from struts2 or do I have to use a plugin or something like that? Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide information, just saying you get an exception isn't much to go on. It *sounds* like the select box is no longer being filled, because you've gone through a request cycle and lost the original list. If that's true, [this](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-do-we-repopulate-controls-when-validation-fails.html) will help, and I'll convert this to an answer.

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: Converted to answer; glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When validation fails, it's often necessary to "reload" data for the form page. There's a [FAQ entry that covers repopulating controls after validation](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-do-we-repopulate-controls-when-validation-fails.html), mainly detailing the `Preparable` interface (preferred) and the use of the `<s:action>` tag (there are some subtle gotchas that can pop up with this, but in general, it's also okay).